# 4:**Count/sum rows in multiple related tables

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have a complex select that - when simplified - looks like this:

```
select m.ID,
  (select sum(AMOUNT) from A where M_ID = m.ID) sumA,
  (select sum(AMOUNT) from B where M_ID = m.ID) sumB,
  .....
from M;
```

The tables A,B,... have a foreign key M_ID pointing into table M.
The problem is that this select is very slow. I'd like to rewrite it using table joins, but I don't know how, because

```
select m.ID
  sum(a.AMOUNT),
  sum(b.AMOUNT),
  .....
from M
join A on a.M_ID = m.ID
join B on b.M_ID = m.ID
....
group by m.ID;
```

gives incorrect (much higher) sum results, as each row in A or B can be counted multiple times.

Is there a way how to write that select optimally using e.g. analytical functions or some other ways?

**Edit:**
The explain plan for the original (not simplified) select looks like this:

```
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT              |                           |
|   1 |  SORT AGGREGATE               |                           |
|*  2 |   FILTER                      |                           |
|*  3 |    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| WORKITEM                  |
|*  4 |     INDEX SKIP SCAN           | WORKITEM_U01              |
|*  5 |    FILTER                     |                           |
|*  6 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL         | RPRODUCT_INVENTORY_MASTER |
.....
|  31 |  SORT AGGREGATE               |                           |
|* 32 |   FILTER                      |                           |
|* 33 |    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| WORKITEM                  |
|* 34 |     INDEX SKIP SCAN           | WORKITEM_U01              |
|* 35 |    FILTER                     |                           |
|* 36 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL         | RPRODUCT_INVENTORY_MASTER |
|  37 |  SORT GROUP BY                |                           |
|  38 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL           | RPRODUCT                  |
```

That's why I want to optimize it. Moreover, the AWR report shows that this select has 50000 gets/exec.

**Edit2,3:**
The whole select looks like this:

```
SELECT rprd.ID,
  rprd.NAME,
  (select sum(AMOUNT) from WORKITEM
    where ACTION='REMOVE'
      and trunc(CREATED_DATE) = to_date(:1,'DDMMYYYY')
      and PAYEE_ID in
          (select rim.RPRODUCT_ID from RPRODUCT_INVENTORY_MASTER rim
            where  rprd.ID = rim.RPRODUCT_ID
              and rim.INVENTORY_DATE = to_date(:2,'DDMMYYYY')),
  .....
  (select sum(AMOUNT) from WORKITEM
    where ACTION='COLLECT'
      and trunc(CREATED_DATE) < to_date(:11,'DDMMYYYY')
      and PAYEE_ID in
          (select rim.RPRODUCT_ID from RPRODUCT_INVENTORY_MASTER rim
            where  rprd.ID = rim.RPRODUCT_ID
              and rim.INVENTORY_DATE < to_date(:12,'DDMMYYYY'))
FROM RPRODUCT rprd 
GROUP BY rprd.ID, rprd.NAME 
ORDER BY rprd.ID
;
```

I didn't write it :-), I'm about to re-write it. Note, there are differences in comparison operators, in ACTION values, in dates to compare INVENTORY_DATE to.

**Edit4:**
I tried to rewrite the query like this (and the exec plan looks better), but have run into the "row multiplicity" issues described above:

```
with RPRODUCT_INVENTORY_MASTER# as (
    select RPRODUCT_ID, min(INVENTORY_DATE) INVENTORY_DATE
      from RPRODUCT_INVENTORY_MASTER
      group by RPRODUCT_ID),
  WORKITEM# as (
    select AMOUNT, PAYEE_ID, ACTION, trunc(CREATED_DATE) CREATED_DATE
      from WORKITEM
      where ACTION in ('REMOVE','ADD','COLLECT')
  )
select rprd.ID,
  rprd.NAME,
--  sum(wip2.AMOUNT), -- this is singular because of '=' in inventory_date comparison
  sum(abs(wip4.AMOUNT)),
  .....
  sum(wip12.AMOUNT)
from RPRODUCT rprd
left join RPRODUCT_INVENTORY_MASTER# rim4 on rim4.RPRODUCT_ID = rprd.ID 
  and rim4.INVENTORY_DATE <= to_date(:4 ,'DDMMYYYY')
left join WORKITEM# wip4 on wip4.PAYEE_ID = rim4.RPRODUCT_ID
  and wip4.ACTION='REMOVE'
  and wip4.CREATED_DATE = to_date(:3 ,'DDMMYYYY')
.....
left join RPRODUCT_INVENTORY_MASTER# rim12 on rim12.RPRODUCT_ID = rprd.ID 
  and rim12.INVENTORY_DATE < to_date(:12 ,'DDMMYYYY')
left join WORKITEM# wip12 on wip12.PAYEE_ID = rim12.RPRODUCT_ID
  and wip12.ACTION='COLLECT'
  and wip12.CREATED_DATE < to_date(:11 ,'DDMMYYYY')
group by rprd.ID, rprd.NAME 
order by rprd.ID
;
```

RPRODUCT_INVENTORY_MASTER# always gives at most one row for each rprd.ID. WORKITEM# can have any number of rows for each RPRODUCT_ID = rprd.ID.

Comment: Before rewriting the query, maybe you should make sure the one you have is optimized. Do you have a query plan? Did you check indexes? How big are these tables? I wouldn't be so sure that other queries perform better than this one, if you have the correct indexes and all.

Comment: I added an answer to (some of) your questions to my original question. I don't expect that indexes would be of any use on this type of query, I expect hash joins.

Comment: Ok. That info is useful as it shows us the query is much more complex than what you originally proposed. But since this is an optimization question, I don't think it is necessarily related to the form of the query (JOINs vs subSELECTs). It just takes 1 or 2 unindexed table accesses on a big table to ruin a query performance. I suggest you post the entire query and the entire explain plan. You may just have problems with *some* complex WHEREs or subSELECTs.

Comment: In general, you're right. But the table RPRODUCT (M) has currently about 100 rows and spans 5 blocks, RPRODUCT_INVENTORY_MASTER has about 550 rows and 5 blocks, WORKITEM has 4500 rows and 88 blocks. This alone couldn't cause 50000 gets/exec, this must be due to a bad exec plan.

Comment: As to EDIT4: I must admit, I liked the original query much better. I know the optimizer does better on joins than on sub-queries so far, but I don't find it very readable to join all that stuff together and finally condense it all to get the desired results. In your case you would have to divide thus: with four tables outer joined a, b, c, and d: nvl(sum(a.AMOUNT), 0) / greatest(count(distinct b.id), 1) / greatest(count(distinct c.id), 1) / greatest(count(distinct d.id), 1).

Comment: A simpler option might be to replace the IN clauses with EXISTS clauses. So far the optimizer handles them better. (I am sure this will change someday and all this re-writing won't be necessary anymore. But right now the optimizer prefers EXISTS.) I still like the second query given in my answer which happens to be the same way suggested by shadow.

Comment: I consider the original select more readable too, but it is slow. The idea with EXISTS is nice, but (I tried it) it produces the same exec plan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is a typical problem. I like your original query for its clarity. However, if running in performence issues, one has to think of other options.

Here is one option. As A and B get multiplied you could simply divide the sum by the related count. Well, admittedly this looks kind of strange though.

```
select m.ID
  sum(a.AMOUNT) / count(distinct b.id),
  sum(b.AMOUNT) / count(distinct a.id),
  .....
from M
join A on a.M_ID = m.ID
join B on b.M_ID = m.ID
....
group by m.ID;
```

The other option, which I would prefer is to build groups, so as not to have multiple A and B per m.id in the first place:

```
select m.ID
  a_agg.SUM_AMOUNT,
  b_agg.SUM_AMOUNT,
  .....
from M
join (select M_ID, sum(AMOUNT) as SUM_AMOUNT from A group by M_ID) a_agg
  on a_agg.M_ID = m.ID
join (select M_ID, sum(AMOUNT) as SUM_AMOUNT from B group by M_ID) b_agg
  on b_agg.M_ID = m.ID
```

EDIT: In case an M_ID might not have any A or any B, you would have to replace the joins with LEFT JOIN in both queries. Then in the first query select:

```
nvl(sum(a.AMOUNT), 0) / greatest(count(distinct b.id), 1),
nvl(sum(b.AMOUNT), 0) / greatest(count(distinct a.id), 1),
```

And in the second query:

```
nvl(a_agg.SUM_AMOUNT, 0),
nvl(b_agg.SUM_AMOUNT, 0),
```

EDIT: Here is your query modified. The trick is to join with distinct rims.

```
SELECT 
  rprd.ID,
  rprd.NAME,
  nvl(same_date.SUM_AMOUNT, 0),
  .....
  nvl(earlier_date.SUM_AMOUNT, 0)
FROM RPRODUCT rprd 
LEFT JOIN
(
  select rim.RPRODUCT_ID, sum(w.AMOUNT) as SUM_AMOUNT
  from
  (
    select distinct RPRODUCT_ID 
    from RPRODUCT_INVENTORY_MASTER
    where INVENTORY_DATE = to_date(:2,'DDMMYYYY')
  ) rim
  left join WORKITEM w 
    on w.PAYEE_ID = rim.RPRODUCT_ID
    and w.ACTION = 'REMOVE'
    and trunc(w.CREATED_DATE) = to_date(:1,'DDMMYYYY')
) same_date on same_date.RPRODUCT_ID = rprd.ID
LEFT JOIN
(
  select rim.RPRODUCT_ID, sum(w.AMOUNT) as SUM_AMOUNT
  from
  (
    select distinct RPRODUCT_ID 
    from RPRODUCT_INVENTORY_MASTER
    where INVENTORY_DATE < to_date(:12,'DDMMYYYY')
  ) rim
  left join WORKITEM w 
    on w.PAYEE_ID = rim.RPRODUCT_ID
    and w.ACTION = 'REMOVE'
    and trunc(w.CREATED_DATE) < to_date(:11,'DDMMYYYY')
) earlier_date on earlier_date.RPRODUCT_ID = rprd.ID
GROUP BY rprd.ID, rprd.NAME 
ORDER BY rprd.ID
;
```

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding, but A and B dont get multiplied, they get added.  I cant see how your math is supposed to work on the first one.  As for the the second I'd imagine that it would perform exactly the same as the OP's as you're just moving the subselect to the join.

Comment: @paqogomez: By multiplying I mean that if you get three A records for an m_id and four B records, then you get 3 x 4 = 12 records for the m_id, which is the reason that the sums get multiplied also. Instead of sum = n for table A, you would get sum = 4 x n. You would have to divide by the B Count which is 4 to get the sum actually wanted. As for the second query: Rather than scanning A and B for each M, these scans are done just once beforehand. True, Oracle's optimizer might notice and make the same plan for both queries.

Comment: I see now, I hadnt noticed that you were dividing b from a and vice versa. Points for cleverness.

Comment: Thanks Thorsten, I prefer the first option, though I will have to handle division by 0. The second option cannot be applied, the sub-selects are too complicated for this - see Edit2 in my original post. Moreover, in the second option I would force a one particular exec plan, I prefer to leave the exec plan decision on the optimizer.

Comment: I see. As to the first query: You are right; if it is possible not to have any A or B for an m_id, then you would need outer joins and treat a count of zero like a count of 1. As to the second query: Well, we are takling about optimization. In spite of having written a good query you are facing performance issues, so we must look for ways to think of re-writing the query. To say " I want to combine each M with its A sum and B sum" doesn't sound worse to me than "I want to combine all M, A and B to find the A and B sums per M".

Comment: As to complexity: If you repeatedly need the same sub-queries, you can write with clauses for these.

Comment: I have already re-written the select using WITH, but then I ran into the issue I tried to describe in my original query. See Edit3 and Edit4 in my original post.

Comment: I've updated my answer so to show you how to use the second technique on your query.

Comment: I've combined your first suggestion with my select in Edit4, and got an exec plan that looks good to me. Unfortunately, the whole select is only 3 times faster now, but also it needs 100-times less gets. Unfortunately it uses 2 physical reads/exec which causes its slowness. Where come the physical reads from?

Comment: As far as I know that's a matter of luck (or with the queries executed before to be more precise). If the data happens to be already in memory then no physical reads are needed to get to the data, otherwise yes.

Comment: I've tried to re-write the select in the way of your last suggestion (the last code-block in this answer), and it is even faster than my last try along the lines of Edit4! One third faster, a little less gets, and still 2 phys reads on each exec. Thanks a lot! Of course, when data change, this can change too, but your select is much more readable anyway. Concerning the 2 phys reads, it may be that the WITH causes writes into the TEMP tablespace - because these phys reads are on every exec, no caching takes place.

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
select m.ID,
a.aamount,
b.bamount
from M
inner join 
(
select M_ID,sum(AMOUNT) as aamount
from A group by M_ID
) a
on a.M_ID = m.ID
inner join 
(
select M_ID,sum(AMOUNT) as bamount
from B group by M_ID
) b
on b.M_ID = m.ID;
```

Comment: Thanks, but I cannot do it this way, the sub-selects are too complicated for this case. See Edit2 in my original question.

Answer (score 0):

This should work regardlessly of number of m_id rows in A, B, C, ... tables:

```
select
  M.id,
  sum(decode(u.src, 'A', u.sumx, 0)) sum_a,
  sum(decode(u.src, 'B', u.sumx, 0)) sum_b,
  sum(decode(u.src, 'C', u.sumx, 0)) sum_c,
  ...
from M,
  (select 'A' src, m_id, sum(amount) sumx from A group by m_id
  union all
  select 'B', m_id, sum(amount) from B group by m_id
  union all
  select 'C', m_id, sum(amount) from C group by m_id
  ...
  ) u
where
  M.id=u.m_id
group by
  M.id;
```

Comment: Well, yes, but effectively this select would lead to an almost identical exec plan as in the original select, wouldn't it?